# Example for a sequence of operators converging pointwise, but not with respect to the operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to understand the following example.

Define $$T_n: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$$
$$T_n(x)=(0, ..., 0, x_{n+1}, ...).$$

It's rather clear that $T_n(x)$ converges for $0$ for every $x \in l^2$. However, the script says that $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge with respect to the operator norm.

The last part is difficult to understand for me. So I thought maybe my understanding of the first statement is wrong?

If we arbitrarily choose $x \in l^2$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i|^2 < \infty$. We also have that $\left|| T_n(x) \right||= \left( \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |x_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ is decreasing for increasing $n$. If look at the subsequence of all $x_i \neq 0$, it becomes strictly decreasing and by assumption bounded. So $\left|| T_n(x) \right||$ should converge to $0$.

Is that reasoning flawed?

For the operator norm, I have to look at the limit of $$\left|| T_n \right|| = \sup \left\{ \left|| T_n(x) \right|| : x=1 \right\}.$$ Intuitively, it makes sense that the limit is not $0$, since infinitely many elements of my sequence always remain and thus the supremum over all $x \in l^2$ shouldn't be $0$.

Yet, I have some trouble with the coincidence of limit and supremum here. E.g., how could I calculate the supremum for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Does the sequence $\left|| T_n \right||$ converge to a value that is not zero or not at all?

Clearly, I wouldn't know how to properly examine this problem. Occurrence of suprema in general has always provided difficulties for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if $x = (a_k) \in \ell^2$ is the sequence with $a_{n+1} = 1$ and $a_k = 0$ otherwise, we have that
$$\|T_n x\|_{\ell^2} = \|(0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots)\|_{\ell^2} = 1.$$
Hence $\|T_n\|_{\text{op}} \geq 1$.

On the other hand, note that for any $y = (b_k) \in \ell^2$,
$$\|T_n y\|_{\ell^2} = \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty |b_k|^2 \leq \sum_{k = 1}^\infty = \|y\|_{\ell^2}.$$
Therefore
$$\|T_n\|_{\text{op}} = \sup \{ \|T_n y\|_{\ell^2} : \|y\|_{\ell^2} = 1\} \leq 1.$$

Since $\|T_n\|_{\text{op}} \geq 1$ and $\|T_n\|_{\text{op}} \leq 1$, it must be that
$$\|T_n\|_{\text{op}} = 1.$$